# Webpack how to ignore the imported files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Let's say I have the files `Header.jsx`, `Footer.jsx`, `Home.jsx` and the `App.jsx` with the following contents:

```
// Header.jsx
import React from 'react';
export default function() {
    return <h1>This is a header</h1>;
}

// Footer.jsx
import React from 'react';
export default function() {
    return <h1>This is a footer</h1>;
}

// Home.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Header from 'Header.jsx;
import Footer from 'Footer.jsx;
export default function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <h1>This is home</h1>
          <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from 'Home.jsx';

const reactRoot = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(reactRoot, <Home />);
```

Now, when I use Webpack and `App.jsx` as an entry point, I'll get all the files that's been referenced in the final bundle.

So, I'll be including the app bundle like so and that'll be all.

```
<script src="app.23998992429929.js" />
```

But, I have the need to import it in the following way:

```
<script src="Header.jsx" />
<script src="Footer.jsx" />
<script src="Home.jsx" />
<script src="App.jsx />
```

The entry points are all sorted and I am able to get the above structure. But `App.jsx` still has all the code that's being imported from `<script />` tags which I do not want.

The above is a dumbed down example. The reason I am doing this is to get coverage report of individual components after a RSpec feature test.

So is there a way to exclude the `import ... from '...';` from the output?

I think `externals` maybe of help here but I don't know how to do so when the modules are files.

Comment: Honestly still not sure what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) configurations:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    Header: 'Header',
    Footer: 'Footer',
    Home: 'Home',
    App: 'App'
  }
};
```

The `externals` configuration option provides a way of **excluding dependencies from the output bundles**. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any end-user application) environment.

-From docs